# How to fix error in bitrise with android project

Tags: android, kotlin, bitrise

Everything works fine for years and after one more build, error start occurs with build failed in `bitirse`.

```
install-missing-android-tools@3.0 (exit code: 1)    

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'src'.
> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not resolve commons-io:commons-io:2.6.
     Required by:
         project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.3
         project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.3 > androidx.databinding:databinding-compiler-common:7.0.3
      > Skipped due to earlier error
   > Could not resolve com.squareup:javapoet:1.13.0.
     Required by:
         project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.3
[...]
and all others libs don't work
```

I'm not sure where to start find the source of the problem.
I have done my research and somehow it could be related to libraries, but that is only assumption.
Thanks